# Column tbody height not being applied using calc in Firefox

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a simple table with an header and a table content that has a fixed height. It works perfectly in Chrome, Edge and IE11, but not in Firefox.

The table is structured like that:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>...</th>
      <th>...</th>
      <th>...</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The table is wrapper into a div that has a `width of 100% and a height of 400px`.

Other than that, the css relative to that table is something like:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

thead {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

tbody {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 30px); // <--- Not working properly on firefox
}
```

Setting the `tbody` height to a fixed value (for example to 200px;) fix the issue.

I don't get it what am I doing wrong, if someone has an idea feel free to help me out.

Here's a [Stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oi6i3n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) to reproduce the problem:

**EDIT: How I solved it**

In the table's component, I added those lines in the constructor:

```
 const userAgent = (navigator && navigator.userAgent || '').toLowerCase();
this.isFirefoxOrIE = !!userAgent.match(/(?:firefox|fxios)\/(\d+)/) || !!userAgent.match(/(?:msie |trident.+?; rv:)(\d+)/);
```

and then I created a function to set dinamically the height of my `tbody` like that:

```
public getTableBodyHeight(): string {
        return (this.isFirefoxOrIE) ? `${document.getElementsByClassName('my-container')[0].parentElement.parentElement.clientHeight - 41}px !important` : 'calc(100% - 31px)';
    }
```

Finally applied the result in the html:

```
<tbody [style.height]="getTableBodyHeight()">
   ...
</tbody>
```

Comment: Is Firefox interpreting the 100% as one would expect - i.e. the height of its parent (which is table)? Whereas the other browsers seem to take it as the height of the containing div which is the grandparent's height.

Comment: To me is not interpreting good, since even IE is doing great. Everything has an height set, from the body to the td/th inside the thead and tbody.

Answer (score 0):

if all other components heights in the page are known, it's possible to use VH units

```
--page-header-height: 300px
height: calc(100vh - var(--page-header-height) - 30px);
```